Replace characters in array
Sub REPCHAR()
    Dim Massive(2), DATA As Variant, RES As Variant, LC As String, I As Long, N As Long
    Dim Dic: Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    With Sheets("1")
    LC = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    DATA = .Range("D1:E" & LC).Value
    RES = .Range("D1:E" & LC).Value
    For I = 1 To 2
        If Not Dic.Exists(DATA(I, 2)) Then
            Massive(2) = Replace(DATA(I, 2), "A", "А")
            Massive(2) = Replace(DATA(I, 2), "B", "В")
            Massive(2) = Replace(DATA(I, 2), "E", "Е")
            Massive(2) = Replace(DATA(I, 2), "K", "К")
            Massive(2) = Replace(DATA(I, 2), "M", "М")
            Massive(2) = Replace(DATA(I, 2), "H", "Н")
            Massive(2) = Replace(DATA(I, 2), "O", "О")
            Massive(2) = Replace(DATA(I, 2), "P", "Р")
            Massive(2) = Replace(DATA(I, 2), "C", "С")
            Massive(2) = Replace(DATA(I, 2), "X", "Х")
            Massive(2) = Replace(DATA(I, 2), "T", "Т")
            Dic(DATA(I, 2)) = Massive
        End If
    Next I
    For N = 1 To UBound(DATA)
        On Error Resume Next
            RES(N, 1) = Dic(DATA(N, 2))(2)
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next N
    
    .Range("D1:E" & LC) = RES
    End With
End Sub

Hello,
I need a macro to replace latin letters to similar cyrillic letters.
This macro replaces only one letter. How to edit and replace all 11 letters. I am not good in arrays. Any help is appreciated.

Your code  has a number of incorrect assumptions and lacks clarity in terms of explaining  what it is you are trying to so.  If you could add a text explanation of what you are trying to achieve you may get some more informative answers.

Your macro replaces only one letter "Т"->"T".
Try
Dic(DATA(I, 2)) = _ 
 Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace _
     (Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace( _
     DATA(I, 2) _
     , "A", "А"), "B", "В"), "E", "Е"), "K", "К"), "M", "М"), "H", "Н") _
  , "O", "О"), "P", "Р"), "C", "С"), "X", "Х"), "T", "Т")


Push out the replacements to a standalone function and call that from your main code:
Function ReplaceChars(ByVal txt As String) As String
    Dim i As Long, arr
    'Pairs of letters and their replacements
    arr = Array("A", "?", "B", "?", "E", "?", "K", "?", "M", "?", "H", "?", _
                "O", "?", "P", "?", "C", "?", "X", "?", "T", "?")
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) Step 2
        txt = Replace(txt, arr(i), arr(i + 1))
    Next i
    ReplaceChars = txt
End Function

